# How to get children of HTML custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm writing a scraper with puppeteer and I need to fill the fields of a form built with Aura js. The problem is I'm not able to reach the input and password fields because they're inside a custom element:

```
<lightning-input class="input sfdc_usernameinput slds-form-element" data-aura-rendered-by="116:0" lightning-input_input-host=""><span lightning-input_input="" data-aria="" class="slds-assistive-text"></span><label lightning-input_input="" for="input-5" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex slds-assistive-text">Username</label>
    <div lightning-input_input="" class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
        <input lightning-input_input="" type="text" id="input-5" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Username" class="slds-input">
    </div>
</lightning-input>
```

And when I try:

```
await page.type('#input-5', 'myusername');
```

it throws the error:

`Error: No node found for selector: #input-5`

This is confirmed if I try document.getElementById('#input-5') in browser console.

So how do I get that input?

EDIT: Adding a screenshot that shows what happens here: the markup with children elements but no way to access to them.

[image: custom element lightning-input with some debug]

Comment: Are you sure that it's because they're inside a custom element and not because you're trying to get it before the DOM has fully loaded?

Comment: @JamesHill confirmed, as I wrote that happens even with the browser console (so when the page is fully loaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you're looking for are encapsulated in the [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) thus making them hidden from the normal DOM query methods.

You can still query them like this:

```
document.querySelector("lightning-badge").shadowRoot.querySelector('#input-5')
```

Example: on [this Aura demo page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:badge/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleBadgeWithIcon) I can get text of a lightning badge with this code:

```
document.querySelector("lightning-badge").shadowRoot.textContent
```

> "Start Position"

This query can of course can be executed in a `page.evaluate` method with puppeteer as well.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.